# jquery click radio button clicks another

Tags: jquery

I am having trouble with some code. I have a table with a number of radio button options in each cell if one is clicked It then looks up what is the opposite set and then clicks that set.

All is working well except when I click the first one in the set it does not click the opposite one.

I have set up the code in JSFiddle, would be grateful for any help.

https://jsfiddle.net/mikeu/yx89h5nn/

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="cb">
      <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" data-opposite-name="_S1">
        <label class="btn btn-xs">
          <input type="radio" name="_L1" value="a">
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-xs">
          <input type="radio" name="_L1" value="b">
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-xs">
          <input type="radio" name="_L1" value="c">
        </label>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="cb">
      <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" data-opposite-name="_L1">
        <label class="btn btn-xs">
          <input type="radio" name="_S1" value="a">
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-xs">
          <input type="radio" name="_S1" value="b">
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-xs">
          <input type="radio" name="_S1" value="c">
        </label>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


$('input:radio').change(function () {
  var opposite = $(this).parent().closest('div').data("opposite-name");

  if ($('*[name="' + opposite + '"]').val() != $(this).val()) {
    $('*[name="' + opposite + '"][value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').click();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test the `:checked` radio button value. So the condition should be

```
if($('*[name="' + opposite + '"]:checked').val() != $(this).val())
```

Also, instead of executing `click()`, you should set the `checked` property.

*complete code*

```
$('input:radio').change(function() {
    var opposite = $(this).closest('div').data("opposite-name");
    if ($('*[name="' + opposite + '"]:checked').val() != $(this).val()) {
        $('*[name="' + opposite + '"][value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/nsrj9o1p/)

Answer (score 0):

What this part supposed to do?

`if ($('*[name="' + opposite + '"]').val() != $(this).val())`

Delete this code works correctly.